# DB2-LUW: UNION in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, union, db2-luw

I'm trying to run the following simple select in a stored procedure:

```
P1: BEGIN

    DECLARE v_uid INTEGER;
    
    SELECT  UID
    INTO    v_id
    FROM    TableA
    UNION 
    SELECT  UID
    FROM    TableB
    ;
    
END P1
```

It works fine on a z/OS database but with a LUW database I receive the following error:

```
 Create‬‎ ‪stored‬‎ ‪procedure‬‎ ‪returns‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎:‪‬‎ ‪‬‎-‪104‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎:‪‬‎ ‪42601‬‎.‪
 TEST‬‎:‪‬‎ ‪25‬‎:‪‬‎ ‪An‬‎ ‪unexpected‬‎ ‪token‬‎ ‪‬‎"‪SELECT UID 
 FROM TABLEB"‬‎ ‪was‬‎ ‪found‬‎ ‪following‬‎ ‪‬‎"FROM TABLEA UNION"‬‎.‪‬‎ 
 Expected‬‎ ‪tokens‬‎ ‪may‬‎ ‪include‬‎:‪‬‎ ‪ ‬‎"‪‪<space>"‬‎.‪‬‎.‪‬‎ 
 ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪104‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎=‪42601‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪DRIVER‬‎=‪4‬‎.‪24‬‎.‪92
```

Is the use of the UNION keyword not allowed on LUW?

Comment: Remove the semicolon between tableA and union

Comment: sorry, this was just my typo. the problem still persists

Comment: no problem, see my anwer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put union inside a subselect like

```
select uid into v_id from
   (select uid from tablea
    union select uid from tableb);
```